# Windows: Creating software install from a system levem diff

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a base install of a winodws system. I want to take a snapshot. Install some software, take another snapshot, and create a self installing package from the difference. I've used something similar a long time ago (on NT And 2000) but cant remember the name of the utility, nor (apparently) any relevant terms that are putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a software unattended installation.  Take a look [here](http://www.almeza.com/content/view/61/75/) and see if that's what you are looking for.

I also found a site about installing the OS and the application from [sourceforge](http://unattended.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Nope, looking for creating packages (or registry hives and manual copy scripts). Distinctly do not want to use the installation packages.